# how to avoid onError stop the async streaming in rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java

Let me get straight to the problem. I have a list of network calls to make. I am using the `merge` operator of `RxJava` to merge the list of network calls and execute them sequentially and at last get the list of output. Now I am facing a problem. If any of the network call fails in between the next network calls wont be made and the execution stops. How can I make sure that all the network calls in the list are executed inspite of its success or failure?

```
Observable<String> op1 = service1.operation();
Observable<String> op2 = service2.operation();
Observable<String> op3 = service3.operation();

Observable<List<String>> lst = Observable.merge(op1, op2, op3).toList();
```

Here if I observe the `lst` it should return me a list of `Strings` with either the success or failure result.

Comment: Try [`mergeDelayError`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#mergeDelayError-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-).

Comment: As per the documentation its what I am looking for. Let me give it a try and will notify you the result.

Comment: Super!! its working fine @akarnokd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception is a `terminal event` in rxjava and it terminates the stream where it have happened (and any outer stream if you are not using any operator to handle it) . But if you wrap that stream in an inner stream and apply operator `onErrorReturnItem` you can avoid it. The inner stream will be terminated anyway, but instead of passing `onError` to the outer stream by applying `onErrorReturnItem` operator you instead will pass `onNext` to the outer stream and this way outer stream won't be terminated:

```
public static Observable<String> serviceOperation(String param) {
    return Observable.just(param)
            .doOnNext(s -> {
                //simulate error when param is "value 2"
                if (s.equals("value 2")) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Something happened");
                }
            });
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    //here we create a stream and by using concatMap creating another inner stream
    Observable<String> op1 = Observable.just(1)
            .concatMap(integer -> {
                return serviceOperation("value 1")
                        .onErrorReturnItem("Error");
            });

    Observable<String> op2 =Observable.just(1)
            .concatMap(integer -> {
                return serviceOperation("value 2")
                        .onErrorReturnItem("Error");
            });

    Observable<String> op3 = Observable.just(1)
            .concatMap(integer -> {
                return serviceOperation("value 3")
                        .onErrorReturnItem("Error");
            });

    Observable.merge(op1, op2, op3)
            .toList()
            .subscribe(strings -> strings.forEach(System.out::println), Throwable::printStackTrace);
}
```

This will print:

```
value 1
Error
value 3
```

Comment: Even this is a great way of solving the problem. Just wanted to know, is it any different from `mergeDelayError` ?

Comment: `mergeDelayError` collects all exceptions in CompositeException which will be thrown when `mergeDelayError` receives `onComplete` event (in this case after all three service.operation() complete or throw exception). So in my opinion you should use it when you don't care about exception handling. And if you do, then you should use inner stream + `onErrorReturnItem`.

Comment: Amazing explanation..Thanks for this detailed answer. I learnt a lot from this answer. RxJava is so powerful.